# Convert Embeded Graphics to Simple Graphics, ArcGIS

Tags: arcmap, graphics

Is there a way to convert an embedded graphic in an ArcMap document, to a non-embedded graphic?

I have a number of graphics of little trees. They were embedded into an mxd  and I want to convert them back to simple graphics so that I can copy and paste them from one mxd to another without the size changing because of the scale.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Are the embedded graphics a copy and pasted image?  If so what is the format?

Comment: I'm not sure. I received the mxd from someone else. There are no properties to tell me what the format is.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Convert Graphics to Features command to convert them to either ;point, line, polygon, or annotation features.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If the images are added as a separate graphic (i.e. through the menu *Insert → Picture* you can simply right click on it, and select *Copy*.

If the image is used as a marker symbol for a layer, you need to convert it to a graphic first:

- Select one feature on the map using the Select tool: [image: Select tool]
- Right click on the layer in the table of contents, and select *Convert features to graphics*
- Right click on the generated graphic and select *Copy*

To find out if the image is a graphic or a marker symbol, use the Arrow tool [image: Arrow tool] and click on the image. If it is a graphic, it will be selected and blue size handles will be visible.